# Baking diffuse to a second mesh leaves a lot of black pixels in target

Tags: texture-baking

I'm trying to bake lighting into a texture.  At the end of my bake, about half of the pixels in the image appear to be correctly rendered, but the other half are completely black and in a Moire pattern.

I've created a test file where I create a new instance of the monkey, assign it a new material with a new texture and then paint it.  Next, I duplicate my mesh (I do not change its transform) and assign the duplicate a new material with a new blank texture.  Then I select my first object, then the second and go into the Render tab. Under Sampling, I have render samples at 128.  Under Baking, I have Bake Type: Diffuse.  Under Influence, Direct Indirect and Color are checked.  I press Bake and a few seconds later my baked texture is created with the black pixels.

Does this have something to do with overlapping geometry?  None of the tutorials I looked at say I need to tweak the vertices in either my source or destination mesh.

[image]

Left pane: the baked texture.  Right pane - my source mesh and texture.  The bake target has exactly the same mesh and the same transform.

Comment: Try to give a little value to the "extrusion" in "selected to active" section.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.